# Curious error springmvc annotations using scala

Tags: scala, spring-mvc

I thought one of you very clever scala people might be able to explain the following problem.

The following service always returns a 400 (The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().) - one of the less helpful errors from springmvc but it normally happens when a parameter hasn't been properly specified. However, if I remove the line doing the mapping on None it works. Also if I create a local val referring to the param and then map that instead it also works.

```
@RequestMapping(value = Array("/willfail/{param}/"))  
def willFail(@PathVariable param:String):String={
    println("This line never even gets executed.")

    //Remove following line and it works.
    None.map(_ == param )

    //Whatever..
    "somepage"
}
```

It is a bit embarrassing because I dragged everyone kicking and screaming to scala and it is the first case where I feel a bit guilty about it.

Comment: Can you please try specifying the exact name of the param - `@PathVariable("param")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly pointed out by Biju Kunjummen, it's related to reconstruction of parameter names from debug information.

In presence of `None.map(_ == param )` `scalac` for some reason writes different parameter name (`param$1` instead of `param`) into debug information (you can check it with `javap -c -l`), therefore Spring MVC cannot associate parameter with the path variable.

As a workaround you can specify parameter name explictly (`@PathVariable("param")`), it also makes your program work if compiled without debug information.

Comment: Thanks to you both.. although not really the answer i was hoping for ;)